# Как поделить друг на друга два запроса с различными условиями?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица, в которой колонка менеджеров и колонка со статусами. Как посчитать сумму статусов Fully, деленную сумму записей со всеми статусами кроме N/A по каждому менеджеру?

Пытался изобразить таким способом, но ничего не вышло

```
SELECT "Manager Name", ((SELECT count("Performance Score") FROM public.hr_dataset 
WHERE ("Performance Score" = 'Fully Meets'))/ (SELECT count("Performance 
Score") FROM public.hr_dataset 
WHERE ("Performance Score" != 'N/A- too early to review') )) as Perfomance 
FROM public.hr_dataset GROUP BY "Manager Name"
ORDER BY Perfomance DESC;'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT name, SUM(status='Fully')/SUM(Status!='N/A')
FROM table
GROUP BY name
```

или

```
SELECT name, COUNT(CASE WHEN status='Fully' THEN 1 END)/COUNT(CASE WHEN Status!='N/A' THEN 1 END)
FROM table
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: На первый запрос такая ошибка 
UndefinedFunction: function sum(boolean) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "Manager Name", (SUM("Performance Score" ='Fully Meet...
                                ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Второй запрос дал неправильные результаты

Comment: База данных Postgres

Comment: Ясно. Добавьте к тексту вопроса CREATE TABLE таблицы и пример данных в формате INSERT INTO. А также дайте желаемый результат на ИМЕННО ЭТИХ данных, с пояснением, почему именно так. Ненужные для задачи поля и индексы можно опустить.

Comment: Попробуйте `SELECT name, SUM(CASE WHEN status='Fully' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/SUM(CASE WHEN Status!='N/A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM table GROUP BY name`

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Manager, count(*) as FullyStatus, count(*) / NoNA.NoNAStatus as Result 
Group by Manager
Where Status = 'Fully'
```

---

```
Left join (
Select count(*) as NoNAStatus
Where Status <> 'N/A') as NoNA ON true
```

Comment: Syntax error guaranteed.

Comment: Я разделил на два отдельных понятных по смыслу запроса специально; Небольшие исправления позволят избежать ошибки синтаксиса. Главное чтобы автор вопроса понял КАК я это сделал

Comment: Напрасно, я думаю, один синтаксически верный запрос плюс пояснения, что и как он делает, был бы, наверное, более полезен.